# Оформление вводной конструкции на границе частей СПП

Tags: синтаксис, тире, вводные-слова, спп, сложное-предложение

1. *Когда вы уже полчаса бьётесь над задачей, но решение никак не приходит, (—) как правило(,) оно не придёт и через час, поэтому бесполезно продолжать: время будет уходить в никуда.*
2. *Если в ходе логического рассуждения возникло противоречие, (—) возможно(,) какое-то суждение было ложным.* (Пример был добавлен.)

По Розенталю перед вводным словом в качестве дополнительного знака после запятой ставится тире, если вводное слово стоит между частями сложного предложения и по смыслу может быть отнесено как к предшествующей, так и к последующей его частям. По ПАС вводные слова и сочетания слов, стоящие на границе однородных членов или частей сложного предложения и относящиеся к следующему за ними слову или предложению, не отделяются от него запятой (вторая запятая опускается с целью указания на отнесённость вводного слова к последующей части предложения).

Однако и там и там во всех примерах фигурирует ССП. На СПП это правило также распространяется? И всё же, по какому справочнику ставить знаки препинания?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Предложение 1**

**Когда вы уже полчаса бьётесь над задачей, но решение никак не приходит, – как правило,  оно не придёт и через час. Поэтому бесполезно продолжать: время будет уходить в никуда.**

**Примечание.**  Сообщение лучше разбить на два предложения, так как первое предложение разделено **увеличенной паузой** на две части,  а далее (**тоже с паузой**) следует отдельное высказывание. Оформлять всё это  в одну конструкцию сложно и не   имеет смысла.

Возможны **два варианта** оформления подобных предложений.

(1) **Когда вы уже полчаса бьётесь над задачей, но решение никак не приходит, – как правило,  оно не придёт и через час.**

(2) **Когда вы уже полчаса бьётесь над задачей, но решение никак не приходит,  то, как правило,  оно не придёт и через час.**

**В первом варианте** пауза должна быть обозначена, так как два однородных придаточных нужно отделить от главного. Для этого есть **ряд причин:** (1) однородные придаточные времени связаны сочинительным союзом НО, при этом союз КОГДА не повторяется; (2) вводное слово стоит на границе двух частей, но нужно обозначить, что оно относится к главному предложению; (3) одним тире не обойтись в этой сложной конструкции, поэтому нужно использовать запятую и тире.

**Во втором варианте** двойной союз КОГДА...ТО решает все эти проблемы. "Переводить" его в условные необязательно, такой союз используется и в СПП с временными отношениями, например: Когда он входит, то все обычно замолкают.

**Предложение 2**

(1) **Если в ходе логического рассуждения возникло противоречие,  возможно,  какое‑то суждение было ложным.**

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137

7. Если между главной и придаточной частями сложноподчиненного предложения стоит вводное слово, то оно выделяется запятыми на общих основаниях: Он подумал, возможно, что я не хочу с ним встречаться; Если есть спрос на что-либо, значит, будет и предложение.
   Отнесение вводного слова по смыслу к главной или придаточной части определяется условиями контекста.

(2) **Если в ходе логического рассуждения возникло противоречие –  возможно,  какое‑то суждение было ложным.**

Тире ставится для интонационного отделения главной части сложноподчиненного предложения от придаточной. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=142#pp142

В этом случае тире заменяет запятую, сравнить: Сколько бы ни смотреть на море — оно никогда не надоест.

Поэтому логично предположить, что в СПП ставится  тире перед вводным словом вместо первой запятой.

Answer (score 3):

```
 ...на стыке частей сложного 
 предложения ставится тире перед вводной
 конструкцией, чтобы показать, что оно относится
 ко второй части; однако во всех примерах
 фигурирует ССП. На СПП это правило также 
 распространяется?
```

В СПП есть своё правило,правда, вводная конструкция там ни при чём.  Мне кажется, оно вполне сюда подходит:

Запятая и тире в сложноподчиненном предложении ставятся в качестве единого знака:

1) перед главным предложением, которому предшествует ряд однородных придаточных, если подчеркивается распадение сложного целого на две части, например: Кто виноват из них, кто прав, – судить не нам (Крылов); Делал ли что-нибудь для этого Штольц, что делал и как делал, – мы этого не знаем (Добролюбов)

*Когда вы уже полчаса бьётесь над задачей, но решение никак не приходит, — как правило, оно не придёт и через час, поэтому бесполезно продолжать: время будет уходить в никуда.*

Запятая и тире как единый знак после двух придаточных, сложное целое распадается на две части.

Comment: Правда у Розенталя ещё сказано, что "перед главной частью делается длительная пауза", а здесь её нет.

Comment: Как же нет? Есть. Вы же собираетесь тире ставить, а это длительная пауза, а запятая и тире - ещё более длительная.

Comment: Тире в данном случае просто вынужденная мера.

Comment: Но вынужденная мера - распадение предложения на две части, а это пауза. И она в данном случае зависит не от вводного слова, без него она будет стоять там же,она здесь,  чтобы отделить два однородных придаточных от остальной части сложного целого.

Comment: Если бы вводного не было, предложение бы выглядело так: "Когда вы уже полчаса бьётесь над задачей, но решение никак не приходит, оно не придёт и через час, поэтому бесполезно продолжать: время будет уходить в никуда". Так что нет там никакой паузы — ни с вводным, ни без него.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, тут дело не во вводной конструкции "как правило", а в отсутствии второй части союза *когда...то* (*если...то*).

**Если вы уже полчаса бьётесь над задачей, но решение никак не приходит, то оно не придёт и через час, поэтому бесполезно продолжать: время будет уходить в никуда.**

превращается в:

**Если вы уже полчаса бьётесь над задачей, но решение никак не приходит, — оно не придёт и через час, поэтому бесполезно продолжать: время будет уходить в никуда.**

Далее, ничего в принципе не меняется, когда заменяем  *если* на *когда* и добавляем вводную конструкцию:

**Когда вы уже полчаса бьётесь над задачей, но решение никак не приходит, — как правило, оно не придёт и через час, поэтому бесполезно продолжать: время будет уходить в никуда.**

Примечание: для того, чтобы сделать изложение более понятным, я бы поставил точку с запятой или просто точку перед *поэтому*.

Comment: Вторая часть "то" вроде необязательна в обоих союзах, нет? И вы почему-то вводную конструкцию совсем изъяли из своего ответа и изменили "когда" на "если". Хотелось бы получить решение для своей ситуации.

Comment: Я дополнил ответ

Comment: Не ясна аналогия между "когда" и "если". Я не представляю ни одного предложения, где уместно: "когда, то". "Если, то" нормально воспринимается, а "когда, то" совсем не по-русски звучит.

Comment: @Третийглаз, "Когда... то" — я так не пишу, но встречается часто, именно в роли "если...то". Пример: Потому что, когда у мужчины спрашивают: "Любишь?", то, конечно, он отвечает: "Да" ― и мучительно ищет нужные слова… [Ольга Зуева. Скажи, что я тебе нужна... // «Даша», 2004]

Comment: @Третийглаз А вот еще "когда...то", но уже не как "если...то": А когда пришёл в себя, то с удивлением обнаружил подмену. [Александр Дорофеев. Эле-Фантик // «Мурзилка», 2003]

Comment: @М_Г Я Вас понял, да, эти предложения звучат естественно, всё так.

Comment: Вы не ответили. Соотносительное слово "то" необязательно в обоих союзах и может быть опущено, разве не так?

Comment: Слово *то*, как часть составного союза, может быть отброшено. В таком случае часто ставят тире: *Если хочешь удивить аудиторию ― рассказывай про общественных насекомых.* [Кирилл Ефремов. Размышления у книжной полки: Бегство от одиночества // «Знание -- сила», 2003] ; *Если выбор не будет сделан ― деньгами автоматически займётся государственная управляющая компания.* [Вероника Сивкова. На что тратит деньги Пенсионный фонд (2003) // «Аргументы и факты», 2003.06.04]

Comment: Я подумал, что объяснение тут другое. Такие предложения нужно  рассматривать как СПП с инверсией и тире: [Союзное слово Придаточное] – [Главная часть].  (https://dict.nsu.ru/mod/book/view.php?id=12&chapterid=71)

Comment: Тире в этом случае используется для интонационного деления (http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=142#pp142), а не для замещения слова "то". Поэтому это скорее исключение, нежели правило. И всё-таки чаще используется союз "если" без "то". Ответ Людмилы мне кажется вполне убедительным. Про инверсию не соглашусь: у нас нет _необычной последовательности частей_, предложение звучит вполне естественно с расположением "придаточное — главное".